# Charts.js: Moment is not defined (using chart.bundle.min.js)

Tags: javascript, chart.js, momentjs, chart.js2

I have successfully created a chart and configured it using charts.js, but now I want to make the X Axis represent time. When I try to do this using the code below, I get the following console error: Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined. I am using the chart.bundle.min.js because the documentation specifies the bundle comes with moment.js in it so I shouldn't need to download and link moment.js as well.

Here is the code, I got this from a stack member that was answering a question about time axis.
JavaScript:

```
function newDate(days) 
{
  return moment().add(days, 'd'); //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS ACCORDING TO CONSOLE.
};

var config = 
{
  type: 'line',
  data: 
  {
    //Calling the function here, so also shows as error in console.
    labels: [newDate(-4), newDate(-3), newDate(2), newDate(3), newDate(4), newDate(5), newDate(6)], 
    datasets: 
    [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      data: [4, 3, 1, 4],
    }]
  },
  options: 
  {
    scales: 
    {
      xAxes: 
      [{
        type: 'time',
        unit: 'month',
      }],
    },
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/customFitStyling.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/w3c_v4.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like Moment for some reason is not available in the bundle I have tried your code in JSFiddle and there is an error, however is load in Moment.js serpatley it works great.

Maybe use Chart.js and Moment.js and not the bundle, if you are worried about http requests you could always compress and bundle them yourself?

Comment: You are correct: including moment.js separately worked. Should I open an issue on the chart.js github?

Comment: It may be helpful to do so, 1 you may find out that you can use the bundled version, but it maybe behind a namespace or similar, and at the very least it may alert them that it may not be working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the documentation of charts.js :

`When providing data for the time scale, Chart.js supports all of the formats that Moment.js accepts. See Moment.js docs for details.`

So, you should use Chart.js api like this :

`var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    displayFormats: {
                        quarter: 'MMM YYYY'
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
})`

not `moment().add()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I originally built a chart with this method, but it didn't display ticks or accept data the way I wanted it to, even with ticks and unit configurations.